# Laravel 10 project with Tailwind can not switch light mode from dark mode

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, flowbite

I have build a new laravel 10 app using tailwindcss.

I am trying two things and can not seem to make work.

I am trying to switch from dark to light mode and then determine which mode I am in.

If i change the mode in my system settings the mode changes on my webapp, so i know the two modes are working.

in my tailwind.config.js , have added darkMode: 'class'

```
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
     darkMode: 'class',
     content: [
     './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
          './storage/framework/views/*.php',
          './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
     ],

     theme: {
        extend: {
             fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
     },

     plugins: [
        forms,
        require('flowbite/plugin')
     ],
   };
```

in my welcome.blade.php i have added , but they both show up.

```
    <div class="hidden dark:flex">
        My SVG if theme is dark
    </div>
    <div class="flex dark:hidden">
        My SVG if theme is light
    </div>
```

i have followed this example
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-dark-mode-switcher-with-tailwind-css-and-flowbite/

i get no javascript errors , but does nothing.

Any suggestions on what step I am missing?

this is the entire blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Palms Owners</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        /* ! tailwindcss v3.2.4 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:#e5e7eb}::after,::before{--tw-content:''}html{line-height:1.5;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-tab-size:4;tab-size:4;font-family:Figtree, sans-serif;font-feature-settings:normal}body{margin:0;line-height:inherit}hr{height:0;color:inherit;border-top-width:1px}abbr:where([title]){-webkit-text-decoration:underline dotted;text-decoration:underline dotted}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;font-size:1em}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}table{text-indent:0;border-color:inherit;border-collapse:collapse}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-weight:inherit;line-height:inherit;color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit],button{-webkit-appearance:button;background-color:transparent;background-image:none}:-moz-focusring{outline:auto}:-moz-ui-invalid{box-shadow:none}progress{vertical-align:baseline}::-webkit-inner-spin-button,::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}summary{display:list-item}blockquote,dd,dl,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,p,pre{margin:0}fieldset{margin:0;padding:0}legend{padding:0}menu,ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}input::placeholder,textarea::placeholder{opacity:1;color:#9ca3af}[role=button],button{cursor:pointer}:disabled{cursor:default}audio,canvas,embed,iframe,img,object,svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}img,video{max-width:100%;height:auto}[hidden]{display:none}*, ::before, ::after{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::-webkit-backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }.relative{position:relative}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.mx-6{margin-left:1.5rem;margin-right:1.5rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-16{margin-top:4rem}.mt-6{margin-top:1.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.mr-1{margin-right:0.25rem}.flex{display:flex}.inline-flex{display:inline-flex}.grid{display:grid}.h-16{height:4rem}.h-7{height:1.75rem}.h-6{height:1.5rem}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.w-auto{width:auto}.w-16{width:4rem}.w-7{width:1.75rem}.w-6{width:1.5rem}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.max-w-7xl{max-width:80rem}.shrink-0{flex-shrink:0}.scale-100{--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;transform:translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y))}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.gap-6{gap:1.5rem}.gap-4{gap:1rem}.self-center{align-self:center}.rounded-lg{border-radius:0.5rem}.rounded-full{border-radius:9999px}.bg-gray-100{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(243 244 246 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-white{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-red-50{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(254 242 242 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-dots-darker{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.22676 0C1.91374 0 2.45351 0.539773 2.45351 1.22676C2.45351 1.91374 1.91374 2.45351 1.22676 2.45351C0.539773 2.45351 0 1.91374 0 1.22676C0 0.539773 0.539773 0 1.22676 0Z' fill='rgba(0,0,0,0.07)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")}.from-gray-700\/50{--tw-gradient-from:rgb(55 65 81 / 0.5);--tw-gradient-to:rgb(55 65 81 / 0);--tw-gradient-stops:var(--tw-gradient-from), var(--tw-gradient-to)}.via-transparent{--tw-gradient-to:rgb(0 0 0 / 0);--tw-gradient-stops:var(--tw-gradient-from), transparent, var(--tw-gradient-to)}.bg-center{background-position:center}.stroke-red-500{stroke:#ef4444}.stroke-gray-400{stroke:#9ca3af}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-right{text-align:right}.text-xl{font-size:1.25rem;line-height:1.75rem}.text-sm{font-size:0.875rem;line-height:1.25rem}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.leading-relaxed{line-height:1.625}.text-gray-600{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(75 85 99 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(107 114 128 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.underline{-webkit-text-decoration-line:underline;text-decoration-line:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.shadow-2xl{--tw-shadow:0 25px 50px -12px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.25);--tw-shadow-colored:0 25px 50px -12px var(--tw-shadow-color);box-shadow:var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow)}.shadow-gray-500\/20{--tw-shadow-color:rgb(107 114 128 / 0.2);--tw-shadow:var(--tw-shadow-colored)}.transition-all{transition-property:all;transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);transition-duration:150ms}.selection\:bg-red-500 *::selection{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.selection\:text-white *::selection{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.selection\:bg-red-500::selection{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.selection\:text-white::selection{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.hover\:text-gray-900:hover{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.hover\:text-gray-700:hover{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.focus\:rounded-sm:focus{border-radius:0.125rem}.focus\:outline:focus{outline-style:solid}.focus\:outline-2:focus{outline-width:2px}.focus\:outline-red-500:focus{outline-color:#ef4444}.group:hover .group-hover\:stroke-gray-600{stroke:#4b5563}.z-10{z-index: 10}@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference){.motion-safe\:hover\:scale-\[1\.01\]:hover{--tw-scale-x:1.01;--tw-scale-y:1.01;transform:translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y))}}@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){.dark\:bg-gray-900{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-800\/50{background-color:rgb(31 41 55 / 0.5)}.dark\:bg-red-800\/20{background-color:rgb(153 27 27 / 0.2)}.dark\:bg-dots-lighter{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.22676 0C1.91374 0 2.45351 0.539773 2.45351 1.22676C2.45351 1.91374 1.91374 2.45351 1.22676 2.45351C0.539773 2.45351 0 1.91374 0 1.22676C0 0.539773 0.539773 0 1.22676 0Z' fill='rgba(255,255,255,0.07)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")}.dark\:bg-gradient-to-bl{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--tw-gradient-stops))}.dark\:stroke-gray-600{stroke:#4b5563}.dark\:text-gray-400{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.dark\:shadow-none{--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;box-shadow:var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow)}.dark\:ring-1{--tw-ring-offset-shadow:var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);--tw-ring-shadow:var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(1px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);box-shadow:var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow), var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000)}.dark\:ring-inset{--tw-ring-inset:inset}.dark\:ring-white\/5{--tw-ring-color:rgb(255 255 255 / 0.05)}.dark\:hover\:text-white:hover{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}.group:hover .dark\:group-hover\:stroke-gray-400{stroke:#9ca3af}}@media (min-width: 640px){.sm\:fixed{position:fixed}.sm\:top-0{top:0px}.sm\:right-0{right:0px}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0px}.sm\:flex{display:flex}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-center{justify-content:center}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width: 768px){.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))}}@media (min-width: 1024px){.lg\:gap-8{gap:2rem}.lg\:p-8{padding:2rem}}
    </style>
    <script>
        // It's best to inline this in `head` to avoid FOUC (flash of unstyled content) when changing pages or themes
        if (
            localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' ||
            (!('color-theme' in localStorage) &&
                window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)
        ) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body class="antialiased">
    <button
        id="theme-toggle"
        type="button"
        class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5"
        >
        <svg
            id="theme-toggle-dark-icon"
            class="w-5 h-5 hidden"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M17.293 13.293A8 8 0 016.707 2.707a8.001 8.001 0 1010.586 10.586z"></path>
        </svg>
        <svg
            id="theme-toggle-light-icon"
            class="w-5 h-5 hidden"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
                d="M10 2a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0V3a1 1 0 011-1zm4 8a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zm-.464 4.95l.707.707a1 1 0 001.414-1.414l-.707-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414zm2.12-10.607a1 1 0 010 1.414l-.706.707a1 1 0 11-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 0zM17 11a1 1 0 100-2h-1a1 1 0 100 2h1zm-7 4a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0v-1a1 1 0 011-1zM5.05 6.464A1 1 0 106.465 5.05l-.708-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l.707.707zm1.414 8.486l-.707.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 1.414zM4 11a1 1 0 100-2H3a1 1 0 000 2h1z"
                fill-rule="evenodd"
                clip-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </button>

    <div class="hidden dark:flex">
        My SVG if theme is dark
    </div>
    <div class="flex dark:hidden">
        My SVG if theme is light
    </div>

    <div class="relative sm:flex  min-h-screen bg-dots-darker bg-center bg-gray-100 dark:bg-dots-lighter dark:bg-gray-900 selection:bg-red-500 selection:text-white">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="sm:fixed sm:top-0 sm:right-0 p-6 text-right z-10">
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Dashboard</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Log in</a>

                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Register</a>
                    @endif
                @endauth
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto p-6 lg:p-8">
            <div class="flex justify-center">
                <img class="block dark:hidden" style="height: 500px;" src="{{ asset('storage/palmslogoTMP.png') }}" alt="Palms Owners Group" title="Palms Owners Group">
                <img class="hidden dark:block" style="height: 500px;" src="{{ asset('storage/palmslogoTMP.png') }}" alt="Palms Owners Group" title="Palms Owners Group">

            </div>
            <div >
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Dashboard</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Log in</a>

                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 font-semibold text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white focus:outline focus:outline-2 focus:rounded-sm focus:outline-red-500">Register</a>
                    @endif
                @endauth
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var themeToggleDarkIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-dark-icon');
    var themeToggleLightIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-light-icon');

    // Change the icons inside the button based on previous settings
    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
        themeToggleLightIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
        themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    var themeToggleBtn = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');

    themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('-ddd---->',);
        // toggle icons inside button
        themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');
        themeToggleLightIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');

        // if set via local storage previously
        if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme')) {
            if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'light') {
                console.log('-----1>');
                document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
                localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
            } else {
                console.log('-----2>');
                document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
                localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
            }

            // if NOT set via local storage previously
        } else {
            if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
                console.log('-----3>');

                document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
                localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
            } else {
                console.log('-----4>');

                document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
                localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

Thanks